# Backing up the OS from a netbook?

Tags: operating-systems, netbook, reinstall

I'm looking at getting a netbook but I see that they don't come with the OS on cd/dvd.  Is there a way for me to make a "backup" of the default install in case I get a virus or HD wipe and need to "re-install" the OS?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do a full image backup (such as what Acronis TrueImage or Norton Ghost would do) to media such as a couple DL-DVD's or even a memory stick, especially if the netbook has a SSD (with only 8-16GB).

https://superuser.com/questions/33653/back-up-software-for-vista looks like a good summary of Windows-specific options for backup software.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bazillion programs that will image the hard drive so that it can be restored in the event of a crash, kluge, etc. Here are some of them:

DriveImage XML,
Acronis True Image,
Norton Ghost,
HDClone,

etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if the notebook doesn't come with a Recovery Disk, chances are you have the option to create one. Some vendors do this. Search a bit around your current installation for such a feature, or check Support on the vendor website.

In any case, you can use Norton Ghost to make a full bootable image of your installation, you can later use for restore purposes.

Norton Ghost [here](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost). A tutorial [here](http://ghost.radified.com/).

Comment: wrong version of ghost :) radified's guide is focused on Ghost 11 (aka Ghost Enterprise)

Comment: Ah, my bad. :) Didn't even noticed. Just C/Ped from google search results list.

Answer (score 0):

The acer aspire has a hidden 8gb partition with the install files in it - you can run an installer or retrigger something in the bios to re-run this and give you a clean install.

Otherwise I would just driveimage the machine once i had removed all the crapware.

Answer (score 0):

most netbooks come with a System DVD.

ASUS netbooks (aka Eee PCs) can easily be restored by pressing F9 at the POST screen. most other manufacturers do have such a restore facility as well, since netbooks don't come with optical drives.

guides to create your own installation media by extracting the installation source from the System DVD are plenty. **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** makes it a breeze to create a bootable USB stick to install Windows from USB.

in case there is NO restore option, you can always create your own rescue disc with **[BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)** & **[Drive Image XML](http://www.runtime.org/peb.htm)**, again, WinToFlash will move BartPE to a USB Stick or SD card in no time.